# How can i resize a prepend-inner-icon in a v-text-field vuetify tag?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm just learning Vue.js & Vuetify and I can't change the size of my icon. Can anyone help me, please?

```
<v-text-field 
    prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
>
</v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put anything you want in that "prepend-inner" emplacement by using slot ( it's an advanced feature in vue)

```
<v-text-field label="Prepend inner">
   <template v-slot:prepend-inner>
      <v-icon x-large>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
   </template>
</v-text-field>
```